# bootstrap popover not show hidden content wrapper

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I need to show bootstrap popover when click in link. I have this JS Code :

```
$(function(){

    $('[data-toggle=popover].tasks-menu').popover({ 
        trigger:'hover', // want to show in click change trigger:'click'
        html : true, 
        content: function() {
          return $('#popover_content_wrapper').html();
        }
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<a class="tasks-menu" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom">Tasks</a>

<div id="popover_content_wrapper" style="display:none">test Now</div>
```

Now, This popover Worked But not show hidden content! how do i can fix this?

[DEMO LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/hmwQQ/)

**EDITED**: i fix this error with [Sridhar R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23130102/3402142). Now i have another problem :

i put this html into PHP loop. this worked but output not true. i need to show tooltip hidden content for each dynamic title like this:

```
<a class="tasks-menu" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom">Tasks</a>

<div id="popover_content_wrapper" style="display:none">test Now</div>

<a class="tasks-menu" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom">Tasks1</a>

<div id="popover_content_wrapper" style="display:none">test Now 1</div>

<a class="tasks-menu" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom">Tasks2</a>

<div id="popover_content_wrapper" style="display:none">test Now 2</div>

<a class="tasks-menu" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom">Tasks3</a>

<div id="popover_content_wrapper" style="display:none">test Now 3</div>
```

FALSE output is :

`when I mouseover to link all content is for Tasks not for tasks 1, tasks 2 ......`

how do i can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$(function(){

    $('[data-toggle=popover].tasks-menu').popover({ 
        trigger:'hover', // want to show in click change trigger:'click'
        html : true, 
        content: function() {
          return $('#popover_content_wrapper').html();
        }
    });

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hmwQQ/1/)

**Update**

```
$(function(){

    $('[data-toggle=popover].tasks-menu').popover({ 
        trigger:'hover',
        html : true, 
        content: function() {
          return $(this).next('#popover_content_wrapper').html();
        }
    });

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hmwQQ/2/)

Comment: Nice Worked!! Thanks Sridhar